# Return response.data not an object array from database

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, sqlite, flask

A table called notes have attributed notesid,notes,notetist,username. The notes attribute is save the text of the note. I successful call the data from backend, but the response doesnt include array notes.

This is app.js fetchNote function:

```
 const fetchNotes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get_Notes', {
      params: { email: uEmail }, // Pass the email as a query parameter
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
      withCredentials: true
    });

    
    console.log('Notes fetched:', response.data); // Display response data
    setNotes(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error fetching notes:', error);
    console.log(error.response.data.message);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    //console.log(error.response.headers);
  }
};
```

This is notebook.js which will display all the notes in this notebook component:

```
const NoteBook = ({notes, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote,handleFetchNote }) =>{


const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ username: '' });

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData();
}, []);

 async function fetchUserData(){
    try {
            const response =  await axios.get('/get_username', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            withCredentials: true
        });
        const fetchedUserData = response.data;
        setUserData(fetchedUserData);
        console.log(response);


        } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
         }
    }

    


return(
    <div id='notehome'>
        <div className='noteContainer'>
            <section id='notesec'>
                <header className='noteheader'>
                     <h1>My Notes</h1>
                 </header>

                <div className='noteList'>
                <div className="row"> Logged in : <strong className="gfg">  {userData.username} </strong>| <a href='/home'> Logout</a></div>

                {notes.map((notes)=>(
                    <Note 
                    id={notes.notesid} 
                    text={notes.notes} 
                    date={notes.date} 
                    handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
                    handleFetchNote={handleFetchNote}/>
                ))}
                
               <Link
                to={{
                pathname: '/createNote',
                state: { handleAddNote }
                }}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCirclePlus} />
                </Link>
                
                </div>
            
            </section>
            
         </div>
    </div>
    
)
```

This is note.js which is the format of each note:

```
const Note = ({notesid, notes, date, handleDeleteNote,handleFetchNote}) =>{


useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchNote();
}, [handleFetchNote]);


return(
    <div className='note'>
        <span>
            {notes}
        </span>
        <div className='notedatedel' >
            <h6>{date}</h6>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} onClick={()=>handleDeleteNote(notesid)} />
            <Link to="/textEdit" style={{ color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline' }}>Edit</Link>
            <Link to={`/editNote/${notesid}`} style={{ color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline' }}>Edit</Link>
            
        </div>
    </div> 
)
}

export default Note;
```

This is backend:

```
@app.route('/get_Notes', methods=['GET'])
def get_Notes():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('email')
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Users Does Not Exist'}), 400

with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #    "INSERT INTO notes (notes, username) VALUES ( ?, (SELECT id from users  WHERE username=?));"
    get_query = "SELECT notes, notesid FROM notes WHERE username = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?);"
    cursor.execute(get_query, (username,))
    all_notes = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    # notes_list = [{'notes': note[0]} for note in all_notes]
    return jsonify(all_notes)
```

This is response.data:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, 

config: {…}, …}
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
data
: 
username
: 
"myemailhahaha"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders
content-length
: 
"40"
content-type
: 
"application/json"
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
(...)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest
onabort
: 
ƒ handleAbort()
onerror
: 
ƒ handleError()
onload
: 
null
onloadend
: 
ƒ onloadend()
onloadstart
: 
null
onprogress
: 
null
onreadystatechange
: 
null
ontimeout
: 
ƒ handleTimeout()
readyState
: 
4
response
: 
"{\n  \"username\": \"yceng0812@gmail.com\"\n}\n"
responseText
: 
"{\n  \"username\": \"yceng0812@gmail.com\"\n}\n"
responseType
: 
""
responseURL
: 
"http://localhost:5000/get_username"
responseXML
: 
null
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
timeout
: 
0
upload
: 
XMLHttpRequestUpload
onabort
: 
null
onerror
: 
null
onload
: 
null
onloadend
: 
null
onloadstart
: 
null
onprogress
: 
null
ontimeout
: 
null
[[Prototype]]
: 
XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials
: 
true
[[Prototype]]
: 
XMLHttpRequest
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```